# How to properly provide api key for GoogleMaps?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Currently, the AppDelegate calls up a static method that provides the API key for GMSServices. The key is correct and the method itself returns true.

`GMSServices.provideAPIKey(ConfigUtils.GoogleMaps.Key)`

Despite this, when I try to open the map, an error

`Exception    NSException *   "Google Maps SDK for iOS must be initialized via [GMSServices provideAPIKey:...] prior to use"  0x000060000383c8d0`
occurs in the application.

Is there anything else I need to do to make GoogleMaps work properly?

I found this in another question:

> This may happen if some of your Google Maps code runs before API key is initialized.

but there is not any Google Maps code before API key initialization.

Comment: Can you show your AppDelegate code?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything else needed to make the Google Maps API work in your app. As long as the reference to your API key is correct, then it might be that you are calling the `provideAPIKey()` in the wrong place within your AppDelegate.

Are you definitely calling `provideAPIKey()` in the correct function within your AppDelegate? It should be called within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function, like so.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Provide the API Key to allow the app to use Google Maps here.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey(ConfigUtils.GoogleMaps.Key)
        
    return true
}
```